# Xydra (Restless) checking out and running in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, rest, maven

I am trying to build a RESTful Web Service running on Google App Engine. I came across two projects which could be useful,

- [RESTless (Xydra)](http://code.google.com/p/xydra/wiki/RestLess)
- [RESTeasy](http://code.google.com/p/gae-resteasy-app/)

When I tried to checkout either of them, I don't a Google App Engine project, but something which I figured out as a Maven Project. After some struggle I could checkout RESTless-demo as a Maven project, but

- It is not a Google App Engine Project and hence I cannot run/deploy it.
- I am not able to change any configuration as Maven reverts any changes I do.

How can I compile (& Deploy) the project? I am new to both GAE, and I don't know anything about Maven. I am basically a Mobile Developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former is a framework, not an application: it's a library you use to build an app. As a result, it's not an app in and of itself.

The latter is a Maven rule for building an App Engine app that includes RESTless. You probably want to read up on a beginner's guide to Maven to learn how to use it, and how to use build rules.

Looking at the demo project, it is indeed an App Engine project (note appengine-web.xml in the WEB-INF directory). According to the pom.xml, it uses the [maven-gae-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/) Maven plugin, the usage page for which is [here](http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/usage.html); docs on the defined goals are [here](http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/).

Comment: I am sorry, but RESTless also has a few demo apps in the repository. I was trying to run one of them. I had also spent substantial amount of time digging about Maven before I posted it here.

Comment: @Codevalley Unfortunately, I'm unable to read what you haven't written in your original question, especially since you said "I don't know anything about maven", which directly contradicts what you just said. Downvoting my answer because it doesn't take into account information you didn't provide in the first place seems unreasonable.

Comment: You have provided any information. A link perhaps? When I said I don't know anything about Maven, I meant that. Does not mean I didn't try to know.